# Catch-all routing using Tipfy

Tags: google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, url-routing, werkzeug, tipfy

Using tipfy, how does one express a catch-all route in urls.py if more specific routes do not match?

Tipfy uses Werkzeug-like routing, so there's this (in **urls.py**):

```
def get_rules(app): 
rules = [ 
    Rule('/<any>', endpoint='any', handler='apps.main.handlers.MainHandler'), 
    Rule('/', endpoint='main', handler='apps.main.handlers.MainHandler'), 
]
```

This will match most random entry points into the application (*app.example.com/foo*, *app.example.com/%20* etc) but does not cover the *app.example.com/foo/bar* case which results in a 404.

Alternatively, is there a graceful way to handle 404 in Tipfy that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

`Rule('/<path:any>', endpoint='any', handler='apps.main.handlers.MainHandler')`

The [path matcher](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.PathConverter) also matches slashes.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Werkzeug sees 'any' as an unexpected keyword argument. Is there an alternate syntax?

Comment: Here's [the docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.PathConverter). Maybe 'any' is confusing it because there's also an any matcher. You could try <path:foobar> to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could write custom middle ware:

```
class CustomErrorPageMiddleware(object):    
def handle_exception(self, e):           
    return Response("custom error page")
```

To enable it add somewhere to `tipfy` config:

```
   config['tipfy'] = {
       'middleware': [
           'apps.utils.CustomErrorPageMiddleware',
       ]
   }
```

It gives you quite a flexibility - you could for example send mail somewhere to inform that there was a problem. This will intercept all exceptions in your application

Comment: This is a nice idea actually.  I'm only accepting the other answer because it more specifically addresses the question of matching the URL, but your point is well-taken. Thanks!